# Does the UMVUE have to be a minimal sufficient statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, point-estimation

I'm studying point estimation and I have found this question that seems pretty tricky to me.

> If $T$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ with $E(T) = \tau(\theta)$, can you say that $T$ is also the UMVUE for $\tau(\theta)$?

Rao-Blackwell theorem states that an unbiased estimator $T$ for $\tau(\theta)$ can be improved using a sufficient statistic $U$ for $\theta$, i.e. $T^*=E[T|U]$ has a variance lower than the one of $T$.

Lehmann-Scheffé theorem states that $T$ must be a function of a complete sufficient statistic in order to be the unique UMVUE for $\tau(\theta)$.

But what about the fact that $T$ is minimal sufficient? Does this provide some results about $T$?

Comment: Hold on a second, are you looking for MVUE or the UMVUE? The 'U' in UMVUE stands for Unique, so saying you are looking for the unique UMVUE is a little confusing.

Comment: @JohnK Oh sorry, in our notation the U stays for Unbiased. The uniqueness derives from Lehmann-Scheffé theorem.

Comment: Here is what I think, the MVUE definitely has to be a sufficient statistic, otherwise you can always get a better estimator by applying the Rao-Blackwell step. The same applies to a minimial sufficient statistic as by definition it is a function of all other sufficient statistics.

Comment: Thus, we can state that being MVUE implies being a minimal sufficient statistic?

Comment: @JohnK The 'U' as I know stands for 'uniform' and not 'unique'. UMVUE is always unique whenever it exists. You know this of course, but this wasn't conveyed properly I feel.

Comment: Related thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167373/what-is-the-necessary-condition-for-a-unbiased-estimator-to-be-umvue.

Answer (score 1):

Since a minimal sufficient statistic is not a complete statistic in general (cf. [Is a minimal sufficient statistic also a complete statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/272531/119261)), the answer to your question is negative.

For a concrete example, consider $X\sim U(\theta,\theta+1)$ where $\theta$ is the parameter of interest. Here $X$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta$ but $X$ is not the UMVUE of its expectation. For details see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3528411/321264) post.